# Inserting a word before a sequence of lowercase letters in a string

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

I am trying to make a function that adds `Math.` before a sequence of lowercase letters in a string.

### For example

I have a mathematical function `AX + sin(B) * C + sqrt(D)`. I have purposely put all variables in uppercase so the only lowercased words are `sin` and `sqrt`.

And I want the function to return `AX + Math.sin(B) * C + Math.sqrt(D)`

### This is my approach so far

```
def finalString(str):
'''Returns the final string'''
    for i in str:
        if str[i].islower() and (not str[i - 1].islower() or i == 0):
            str = str[:i] + "Math." + str[i:]
    return str
```

But that would only mess up the indices.

Could someone help me on this one?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason for un-accepting my answer?

Comment: ...and I have reverted your question to the original one, which has been answered by _two_ users already below.  If you have _another_ question...then ask a new question.  The site does not work this way, that you keep editing your question with follow-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `re.sub` here:

```py
formula = "AX + sin(B) * C + sqrt(D)"
output = re.sub(r'([a-z]+\(.*?\))', r'Math.\1', formula)
print(formula + '\n' + output)
```

This prints:

```
AX + sin(B) * C + sqrt(D)
AX + Math.sin(B) * C + Math.sqrt(D)
```

Note that the regex pattern I use would only match functions with all lowercase names.  This helps to avoid a false flag positive match/replacement.

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub("([a-z]+)","Math.\\1",input_string)`

I think would do it... this is a regex that tells it to replace any lowercase sequence of letters with `Math.<thesequence>`