# Using re.sub() to capitalize a pattern and add some text before that pattern

Tags: python, regex

This post is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66220245/14185615).

So I have the following string.

```
string = "A / (1 + e ^ (-1 * X))"
```

And I want to create a function to output a string that has all **sequences of lowercase letters
that is not followed by parenthesis** in the previous string written in uppercase with a `Math.`

### For example

`(1 + e)` would return `(1 + Math.E)` 
`(5 ^ 2 * pi)` would return `(5 ^ 2 * Math.PI)`

### This is what I have so far

```
re.sub(r'([a-z]+)(?!\(.*?\))(?![a-z])', r'Math.\1', func)
```

The Regex is working fine, but I don't know how to uppercase the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a function, i.e.

```
re.sub(r'([a-z]+)(?!\(.*?\))(?![a-z])', lambda x: f'Math.{x[1].upper()}', s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You might use function as 2nd argument for `re.sub` which should accept match as its single argument and return `str`. For example let say that we want to uppercase all ASCII letters after digit, then we can do

```
import re
def func(m):
    return m.group(1)+m.group(2).upper()
print(re.sub(r'(\d)([A-Za-z]+)', func, 'abc123def ghi456jkl'))
```

Output:

```
abc123DEF ghi456JKL
```

Keep in mind than group numbering starts with 1, not 0 like for python's `tuple`s and `list`s.